# Compact elements in a lattice satisfying ACC

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I am trying to prove that in a complete lattice $L$  satisfying ACC (ascending chain condition), all elements are compact.

To do so, I start taking $x\in L$ and $S\subseteq L$ such that $x\leq \bigvee S$. I have to prove that there exists a finite subset $T$ os $S$ satisfying that $x\leq \bigvee T$, but I don't know how and where to use my hypothesis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in a lattice satisfying (ACC), you can find a finite subset $T$ of $S$ such that $\bigvee T = \bigvee S$.

Assume this is false, ie for any finite $T \subseteq S$, $\bigvee T < \bigvee S$. The game is to build a suitable infinite chain that will contradict (ACC).

First pick any $s_1 \in S$. By hypothesis, $\bigvee \{ s_1 \} = s_1 < \bigvee S$. Hence you must have $s_2 \in S$ such that $s_2 \not \leq s_1$ (since $s_1$ is not a majorant). For such a $s_2$, $\bigvee \{s_1,s_2\} > s_1$.

Once again, because $\bigvee \{ s_1, s_2 \} < \bigvee S$, we can pick $S \ni s_3 \not \leq \bigvee \{ s_1, s_2 \}$. This means that $\bigvee \{ s_1, s_2, s_3 \} > \bigvee \{ s_1, s_2 \}$.

You can go on and build a sequence $(s_i)_{i \geq 1}$ of elements of $S$ such that if for $n \geq 1$, $t_n = \bigvee \{ s_i \mid i \leq n \}$, then $t_{n+1} > t_n$. But now $\{ t_n \mid n \geq 1 \}$ contradict (ACC).

---

You can even prove it directly, if you already know that in a latice $L$ satisfying (ACC), then any non empty subset must have a maximal element (the proof is very similar to the above one). Then you can apply it to the set $B = \{ \bigvee T \mid T \subseteq S, T \text{ finite } \}$ and find a maximal element $m_0 = \bigvee T_0$. For any $s \in S$, $T_0 \subseteq T_0 \cup \{ s \}$ so $\bigvee T_0 = m_0 \leq \bigvee(T_0 \cup \{ s \})$ but $T_0 \cup \{s\}$ is finite thus $\bigvee (T_0 \cup \{ s \}) \leq m_0$ hence $\bigvee(T_0 \cup \{s\}) = m_0$. Since $s \leq \bigvee(T_0 \cup \{s \}) = m_0$ it follows easily that $\bigvee T_0 = m_0 = \bigvee S$.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. By the way, I would like to know if it is true that if all elements are compact; then there exist  maximums for all directed subsets. I think that it is true but I am not able to give a formal argument.

Comment: @John D. Given (ACC), by the argument that Yann Hamdaoui used, $\bigvee U = \bigvee U'$, where $U'$ is a finite subset of $U$. But if $U$ is a directed set and $U'$ a finite subset of $U$, then there exists $u_0 \in U$ such that $\bigvee U' \leq u_0$, so that $\bigvee U = \bigvee U' \leq u_0 \leq \bigvee U$, and therefore $u_0$ is the maximum of $U$. By the way, if the answer Yann Hamdaoui was clarifying enough to you, don't forget to accept it ;)

Comment: But how do I prove that $\bigvee U =\bigvee U'$ if all elements are compact?

Comment: @JohnD. Is your lattice complete ? If yes, take $U$ a directed set, trivially $\bigvee U \leq \bigvee U$ and it is compact thus it exists $T \subseteq U$ finite such that $\bigvee U \leq \bigvee T$. Since $T \subseteq U$ actually $\bigvee T = \bigvee U$. Now you can apply the argument of amrsa : the only problem in his proof was the existence of $T$ such that $\bigvee T = \bigvee U$, which is not given by (ACC), but by compactness of element $\bigvee U$.